# Metaclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a code (for the experiment:)):

```
class A
  class << self
    def self.f
      puts "f"
    end

    def getMetaclass
      class << self
        self
      end  
    end
  end
end

A.getMetaclass.f
```

I understand that metaclass have their metaclass. Сorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the book ["Metaprogramming Ruby" of Paolo Perrotta](http://www.amazon.de/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476), the term metaclass is only mentioned once, instead the term "eigenclass" is used more often. The eigenclass of class A in your example is the metaclass, and it has its own metaclass (not metaclasses). So I have tried to expand your example, and it seems that this chain never ends:

```
class Eigen
  class << self
    def getMetaclass
      self
    end

    def getMetaMetaClass
      class << self
        self
      end
    end

    def getMetaMetaMetaClass
      class << self
        class << self
          self
        end
      end
    end

  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  puts Eigen.getMetaclass
  puts Eigen.getMetaMetaClass
  puts Eigen.getMetaMetaMetaClass
end
```

The result here is:

> ruby eigen.rb

```
Eigen
#<Class:Eigen>
#<Class:#<Class:Eigen>>
```

I only cannot see what to do with such constructions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've read that eigenclasses are only created when they're required. If so, then it's possible to have a "Turtles all the way down" approach.